# How to use bash to archive all directories?

Tags: bash, 7z

I'm trying to learn bash -slowly- but finding it difficult to get a grasp of the more technical aspects without a real-word example that fits something I would want to use. To that end, I'd like to know how to use bash (and 7zip) to archive some photos in preparation for storing them online.

Essentially, I imagine this is as 'simple' as making a .7z archive of each directory, assigning each archive the same name as the relevant directory. All directories have been named without spaces, should that matter.

Grateful for all advice.

Answer (score 4):

The way to compress a directory `foo` to an archive named `foo.7z`
using `7z` is to use command `a` ("add"):

```
7z a foo.7z foo
```

To do so for multiple directories, one could use a loop:

```
for dir in foo bar baz; do
    7z a "$dir".7z "$dir"
done
```

(This is safe against directory names that include spaces, because
`$dir` is quoted, but not against directory names that start with a
dash; those would result in `7z` attempting to interpret them as
options.)

If the name of directories you intend to archive share a pattern, then
you could use that in the for loop, instead of listing all directories
explicitly, e.g. `for dir in [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-*; ...`.

Note that the 7z documentation warns against using the 7z format for
archival purposes on Unix, because it doesn't preserve ownership
information. This may or may not matter for you.

Comment: I don't know if this answers your question; please comment if not.

Comment: Thanks @dhag, the for loop idea is just what I'm looking for.

Unfortunately, the naming pattern I have for the photos isn't as convenient as that, although they all start with six numbers and a dash to signify a date, instead being descriptive of occasions, people, etc. (e.g. "131225-Christmas-Day"). Does this mean I have to explicitly list every directory to be archived (trivial with 'ls', I assume), and that there's no way of more simply having the loop act on all directories?

Comment: I updated my answer to include an example that matches the format you showed: file names starting with six digits, followed by a dash.

Comment: I forgot to say that I don't need to keep any Linux ownerships or permissions in this case, so 7z will be fine.

Comment: Brilliant! Even before watching it do exactly what I wanted, seeing the format of your updated answer and how it applied to my photos was instantly explanatory. Thanks again!

Comment: `7z a -- $blahblah`.